# SQL: How do I merge 2 two columns and delete the unused afterwards, in the same table?

Tags: sql, join, merge

[image: Image of a table]

I have attached an image of my table. I want to know, how I can "merge" two columns "Number1" with "Number2" and then delete one of the columns so it looks like the right table. If the same data already exists in both columns then just ignore. What does it look like in SQL?

Comment: Please add table schema and sample data as text, also tag your database platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a use of coalesce

```
select id, year, month,
coalesce(number1, number2) number
```

This assumes the blanks in your image are `NULL` (integer values cannot be "blank")

**Edit**

If your columns happen to be varchar then try

```
select id, year, month,
coalesce(nullif(number1,''), nullif(number2,'')) number
```

Comment: Hey sTTU, that did not work. The column can take nulls, but in my table these columns are empty. The type is varchar. I found the solution and it's coalesce(NULLIF([number1],' '), [number2]) as [number]

Comment: This is where including your table schema and actual sql platform would have been useful. Have edited above!